# Why don't Catholics believe that Christ's atonement removed Original Sin?

Tags: catholicism, soteriology, original-sin

Original Sin is the Catholic doctrine that all human are born sinners due to the inheritance of the sin of Adam. However, Jesus Christ atoned for the sin of mankind.

Therefore, one would assume the sin of Adam which Man inherited would be included, and thus children would not need to be baptised in order to be saved as they would be innocent.

Why do Catholics believe original sin was not washed away along with other sins?

Comment: In other words: "Why isn't everyone immaculately conceived?"?

Comment: @Geremia to use Catholic terminology, yes.

Comment: Baptism washes away both actual and original sin. What is your point? We still have the stain of original sin and weaknesses caused by actual sin.

Comment: @KenGraham I don't think you are understanding my question. I know Catholics believe "We still have the stain of original sin", my question is WHY this was not atoned for when Jesus died for the sins of the world.

Comment: If it was not atoned for, then baptism would not remove original or actual sin from the soul. In reality baptism does.

Comment: Can you provide a source that Catholicism believes your initial statement and question: **“Why don't Catholics believe that Christ's atonement removed Original Sin?”**

Answer (score 2):

### Original Sin is washed away through Baptism

The Church believes that Christ's atonement removes original sin precisely through baptism.  More generally, in baptism the power of Christ's paschal mystery comes to bear in the recipient, who also becomes a partaker in that paschal mystery and the life of God. For example, we are told that infants are baptized not because they have committed personal sins, but because their nature is tainted by original sin:

> Born with a fallen human nature and tainted by original sin, children also have need of the new birth in Baptism to be freed from the power of darkness and brought into the realm of the freedom of the children of God, to which all men are called. ([*Catechism of the Catholic Church*, 1250](https://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c1a1.htm))

The [*Catechism of the Council of Trent*](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/trentc.htm) tells us that "Baptism is made obligatory after Christ's resurrection."  It goes on:

> This is inferred from the authority of the Prince of the Apostles when
>   he says: Who hath regenerated us into a lively hope, by the
>   resurrection of Jesus Christ from the dead; and also from what Paul
>   says of the Church: He delivered himself up for it: that he might
>   sanctify it, cleansing it by the laver of water in the word of life.
>   ([*Catechism of the Council of Trent*, Part II on baptism](http://www.catholicapologetics.info/thechurch/catechism/Holy7Sacraments-Baptism.shtml))

Catholic Encyclopedia also implies that the atonement is applied through baptism in a paragraph where it argues that baptism, like original sin and the atonement, ought to be applied to all people, even infants:

> Theologians also call attention to the fact that as God sincerely wishes all men to be saved, He does not exclude infants, for whom baptism of either water or blood is the only means possible. The doctrines also of the universality of original sin and of the all-comprehending atonement of Christ are stated so plainly and absolutely in Scripture as to leave no solid reason for denying that infants are included as well as adults. ([Catholic Encyclopedia, Baptism](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02258b.htm))

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105435/discussion-on-answer-by-zippy2006-why-dont-catholics-believe-that-christs-aton).

Answer (score 2):

It would seem you are not in fact asking why Christ's death did not atone for original sin (Catholics believe *it did*), but rather why that atonement does not instantaneously apply to all men. This is a complex theological question that I am underqualified to answer, but I will attempt to do so.

First, let me ask you a related question: Why do Catholics and Protestants not believe that Christ's atonement instantaneously applies to all the personal sin of all men? Rather, they believe that men must take some action (typically confessing and believing) before that atonement is applied to them.

You can see that, though we all believe that Christ's atonement is sufficient for all people, neither Catholics nor most Protestants believe that Christ's atonement is automatically *applied* to all people. Instead, action must be taken. In the case of infant baptism (practiced not only by Catholics, but also by many Protestants), the action is that of the parent, taken on behalf of the child, and along with a commitment to raise their child in the faith.

Interestingly enough, many Protestants who reject infant baptism also believe that original sin is present in people until either repentance or baptism, they just also believe that parents cannot act on behalf of a child in this matter.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Many Protestants would actually say that we are under the influence of original sin until our future resurrection.

Comment: @curiousdannii Yes, though we use slightly different terminology, Catholics believe the same. We would say that "the stain of original sin remains" or that "concupiscence is still present in the baptized."  In other words, though original sin is removed, and its eternal consequences are removed, it's temporal influence remains. We still have the "flesh" we must wrestle against.